# Starting tomcat7 service on OpenShift error

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

Was able to stop the tomcat 7 service on OpenShift, but trying to start it gives an error:

/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start

> Starting tomcat7: touch: cannot touch `/var/run/tomcat7.pid': Permission denied
>   chown: cannot access`/var/run/tomcat7.pid': No such file or directory
>   /etc/init.d/tomcat7: line 181: /var/log/tomcat7-initd.log: Permission denied
>                                                              [FAILED]

Permission is denied to /var/log so I cannot check/change the /var/log/tomcat7-initd.log permissions. No permission for sudo either.

Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted and recreated the OpenShift application.